# An adverb to mean that something looks to be in a certain way but may or may not be so?

Tags: single-word-requests

> This country's ranking is ----- promising, but there are doubts
>   whether they should be taken at face value.

I am not sure about whether such adverbs as "apparently" or "ostensibly" are good here. Are they? Which one is the most idiomatic one?

Comment: _appears promising_ would work perfectly in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look or appear one way, but  possibly be another!

- in semblant   (1366)
- quasi         (1485)
- cloakedly     (1500)
- appearingly   (1554)
- in show       (1556)
- apparently    (1572)
- **appearingly**   (1578)
- seemingly     (1715)
- outwardly
- allegedly

Myriad considerations!   The most idiomatic?

**seem like X** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/seem)

> to appear to be like some kind of person or something.

But, I like one of your choices:

> This country's ranking is **ostensibily** promising, but there are
>   doubts whether they should be taken at face value.

**ostensible**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ostensible)

> Represented or appearing as such; ostensive:

As in: [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ostensible)

> His ostensible purpose was charity, but his real goal was popularity.

Comment: Where did you find the first list, if I may ask?

Comment: OED Historical Thesaurus

Comment: Is there any source to give a definition such as "to look or appear one way, but possibly be another!" and it gives you the words?

Comment: not that i know of ... I I included link to that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"On first appearances," usually as a leading qualifying phrase:

> "On first appearances, this country's ranking is promising."